# iframe not shown in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, iframe, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane where i load some HTML inside. But if there is a iframe with a youtube-video in the HTML-code, it will not show.

```
<p><iframe width="900" height="506" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/tMWq0QIYQ-s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

As you see, there is a youtube-video inside that iframe. But it doesn't show up in my JEditorpane.

Comment: Alternatively, consider `Desktop#browse()`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Can you explain that?

Comment: Two things, HTML support in Java is limited and it's unlikely that the JEditorPane  would be capable of supporting embedded players. Remember, it's not a browser ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you have an alternative for JEditorpane?

Comment: [Desktop.browse(URI);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) - nice @trashgod

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Will it be opened inside my JEditorpane? Because otherwise, it's no solution.

Comment: You could look into embedding a browser within the application otherwise, no, I don think you'll have any luck with JEditorPane

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you know, how to implement a Browser?

Comment: Not anything I've ever had to do, normally I just leave that kind of thing to web browsers...